# i can't add items to a list inside the while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

```
lis=[]

    while True:
        cho=["rock","paper","scissors"]
        us_in=input("rock, paper or scissors:\n")
        co_in=random.choice(cho)
    
        if us_in==co_in:
            res="draw"
        elif us_in=="rock":
            if co_in=="paper":
                res="lost"
            elif co_in=="scissors":
                res="win"
        elif us_in=="paper":
            if co_in=="scissors":
                res="lost"
            elif co_in=="rock":
                res="win"
        elif us_in=="scissors":
            if co_in=="rock":
                res="lost"
            elif co_in=="paper":
                res="win"
        elif us_in=="done":
            break
        
        else:
            print("wrong input")
            continue
    
    
        lis.append(res)
        #print(lis)
    print(lis)
```

first i created a list inside the loop but it didnt work(because it had created a new list at every
loop, right?). However, taking the list out of the loop didn't solve the problem. What should i do?

edit: I tried the exact same code one day later and it worked just fine. I don't know what caused the problem(it printed out only the last result, if it was win it printed only ["win"]) at the first time. I apologize for the unnecessary question. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Apart from the indentation problem at the start, this code works fine to me. It prints the list at the end, and it has the expected content. What is the problem? Why did you tag this with `basic`? Did you read the tag description?

Comment: Works for me too, after fixing the indent and adding the `import random`. What happens when you run your code and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See also [ask].

Comment: @trincot sorry about the tag. i am new here i didnt notice the description.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code you provided should work to add items to the list lis inside the while loop. However, there is one possible issue that might be causing the problem you're experiencing.

It's possible that the code is raising an exception that you're not seeing, which could cause the program to exit the loop prematurely and prevent the list from being updated. One possible way to diagnose this issue is to add a try-except block around the code that updates the list:

```
while True:
    try:
        cho=["rock","paper","scissors"]
        us_in=input("rock, paper or scissors:\n")
        co_in=random.choice(cho)
    
        if us_in==co_in:
            res="draw"
        elif us_in=="rock":
            if co_in=="paper":
                res="lost"
            elif co_in=="scissors":
                res="win"
        elif us_in=="paper":
            if co_in=="scissors":
                res="lost"
            elif co_in=="rock":
                res="win"
        elif us_in=="scissors":
            if co_in=="rock":
                res="lost"
            elif co_in=="paper":
                res="win"
        elif us_in=="done":
            break
        else:
            print("wrong input")
            continue
    
        lis.append(res)
        print(lis)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

This will catch any exceptions that might be raised and print an error message, which can help you diagnose the issue.

Another possible issue is that the loop is running indefinitely and not allowing you to enter anything. In this case, you can try adding a print statement before the user input to make sure the program is running:

```
while True:
    print("loop is running...")
    cho=["rock","paper","scissors"]
    us_in=input("rock, paper or scissors:\n")
    co_in=random.choice(cho)

    # rest of the code...
```

This will print a message each time the loop runs, which can help you see if the program is still running. If you don't see this message, then the loop might be blocked by some other code or issue.

Comment: Wouldn't an uncaught exception terminate the program noisily?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine for me.

```
%Run test.py
rock, paper or scissors:
rock
['draw']
rock, paper or scissors:
paper
['draw', 'lost']
rock, paper or scissors:
paper
['draw', 'lost', 'lost']
rock, paper or scissors:
paper
['draw', 'lost', 'lost', 'win']
rock, paper or scissors:
test
wrong input
rock, paper or scissors:
scissors
['draw', 'lost', 'lost', 'win', 'lost']
rock, paper or scissors:
rock
['draw', 'lost', 'lost', 'win', 'lost', 'win']
rock, paper or scissors:
done
['draw', 'lost', 'lost', 'win', 'lost', 'win']
```